# Error in [R] VennDiagram: When using decimal numbers

Tags: r

- I am using the `draw.quad.venn()` function of package `VennDiagram`.
- The values in my intersections are showing percentages as decimal numbers.
- The values I pass to the function are rounded for 3 digits (e.g. 3.033).

Unfortunately one of the decimal numbers is shown as 0.0970000000000...04 and the remaining values with only 3 decimal places (as expected).

I have no clue why this specific value is shown with so many decimal places.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data and the code that produced the odd result?

Answer (score 0):

The csv-file contains in column1 the labels (not sorted) (A,A_B, A_B_C, ...) and in column3 the decimal numbers.
Here is the code:

```html
library(VennDiagram)

infile = "xxxx.csv"

table <- read.table(file=infile,header=TRUE,sep=";")


C <- table[1,3]
C_D <- table[2,3]
D <- table[3,3]
B <- table[4,3]
B_C <- table[5,3]
B_C_D <- table[6,3]
B_D <-table[7,3]
A <- table[8,3]
A_C <- table[9,3]
A_C_D <- table[10,3]
A_D <- table[11,3]
A_B <- table[12,3]
A_B_C <- table[13,3]
A_B_C_D <- table[14,3]
A_B_D <- table[15,3]

total_A = A+A_C+A_C_D+A_D+A_B+A_B_C+A_B_C_D+A_B_D
total_B = B+B_C+B_C_D+B_D+A_B+A_B_C+A_B_C_D+A_B_D
total_C = C+C_D+B_C+B_C_D+A_C+A_C_D+A_B_C+A_B_C_D
total_D = C_D+D+B_C_D+B_D+A_C_D+A_D+A_B_C_D+A_B_D


draw.quad.venn(area1=total_A,
               area2=total_B,
               area3=total_C,
               area4=total_D,
               n12=A_B+A_B_C+A_B_D+A_B_C_D,
               n13=A_C+A_B_C+A_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n14=A_D+A_B_D+A_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n23=B_C+A_B_C+B_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n24=B_D+A_B_D+B_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n34=C_D+A_C_D+B_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n123=A_B_C+A_B_C_D,
               n124=A_B_D+A_B_C_D,
               n134=A_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n234=B_C_D+A_B_C_D,
               n1234=A_B_C_D,
               category=c("A","B","C","D"),
               fill = c("yellow","blue","red","green"),
               cex=1.5,
               cat.cex=2)
```